# Visualizing Greatest Common Divisor (gcd)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> If a divides b and leaves a remainder c, then gcd (a,b)= gcd (a,c).

The book has given a detailed proof for it. But I want to understand it intuitively.

On diving 15 with 4, remainder is 3. And gcd (15,4) = gcd (3,4). But why is it happening?

Comment: Because the difference between $15$ and $3$ is a multiple of $4$.

Comment: Here's one possible way: for fixed $a$, look at the function $\gcd(a,b)$ with $b$ as the variable. It turns out that this function is periodic with period $a$. For example, if $a=6$, then the first several values of $\gcd(6,b)$ are $1,2,3,2,1,6,1,2,3,2,1,6,\dots$. In other words, the divisors $b$ has in common with $a$ form this periodic pattern: $b+a$ and $b-a$ have the same divisors in common with $a$ that $b$ itself did. (and that's easy to prove) This implies the statement you posted, because $c$ is in the same place in the period-$a$ pattern as $b$ is.

Comment: What proof do you know, and what part of it is not intuitive for you, and why?

Comment: $b$ and $c$ only differ by a multiple of $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$b$ is divisible by $a$ leaving remainder as $c$ hence we can write

$b = ak+c$ where $k$ is an integer and $k\geqslant0$

Now let's say $gcd(a,b)=x$

$\Rightarrow gcd(a,ak+c)=x$

$\Rightarrow a=mx$ and $c=nx$ such that $gcd(m,mk+n)=1$ i.e. $m$ and $mk+n$ don't have any common divisor. (Then only $x$ will be gcd else a multiple of $x$ will become gcd).

Taking Right Hand Side- Now we have to prove that $gcd(mx, nx)=x$ i.e. we have to prove that $m, n$ are coprime (i.e. $m$ and $n$ don't have any common factor).

We already know that $m, mk+n$ don't have any common factor so we can easily deduce that $m$ and $n$ also don't have any common factor. (Proof by contradiction- Let's say $m$ and $n$ have a common factor then $mk+n$ will be divisible by $m$ which is impossible so $m$ and $n$ can't have a common factor.)

Hence it is proved that $m$ and $n$ are coprime so $gcd(mx, nx)$ will be $x$ because $gcd(m,n)=1$